# Add custom columns to select

Tags: laravel, query-builder

I am trying to add custom row and column to all results. I am getting below error,

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.`png` as `badge`, `3`.`5` as `rating` from `instructors` as `i` inner join `use' at line 1 (SQL: select`i`.`id`,`u`.`name`,`i`.`about`,`i`.`price_per_hour`,`u`.`profile_picture`,`https://www`.`pngitem`.`com/pimgs/m/575-5754595_why-bali-best-driver-driver-icons-hd-png`.`png`as`badge`,`3`.`5`as`rating`from`instructors`as`i`inner join`users`as`u`on`u`.`id`=`i`.`user_id`where 0 = 1 and`gender`in (male) order by`i`.`id` desc limit 10 offset 0)

The associated code:

```
public function findInstructors($instrutors, $gender, $offet, $fetch) {

    return DB::table('instructors as i')
        ->select(
            'i.id',
            'u.name',
            'i.about',
            'i.price_per_hour',
            'u.profile_picture',
            'https://www.pngitem.com/pimgs/m/575-5754595_why-bali-best-driver-driver-icons-hd-png.png as badge',
            '3.5 as rating'
        )
        ->join('users as u', 'u.id', 'i.user_id')
        ->whereIn('i.id', $instrutors)
        ->whereIn('gender', $gender)
        ->offset($offet)
        ->limit($fetch)
        ->orderBy('i.id', 'desc')->get();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to stick with Laravel Collection [map()](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections#method-map) function when it comes to adding additional data to a collection.

```
return DB::table('instructors as i')
->select(
    'i.id',
    'u.name',
    'i.about',
    'i.price_per_hour',
    'u.profile_picture', // Notice* column removed from here
    '3.5 as rating'
)
->join('users as u', 'u.id', 'i.user_id')
->whereIn('i.id', $instrutors)
->whereIn('gender', $gender)
->offset($offet)
->limit($fetch)
->orderBy('i.id', 'desc')
->get()
->map(function($row) {
    // Here you can add like this. Keep in mind, this will be common for all the rows.
    $row['badge'] = 'https://www.pngitem.com/pimgs/m/575-5754595_why-bali-best-driver-driver-icons-hd-png.png';
    return $row;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

mysql understand

```
  'https://www.pngitem.com/pimgs/m/575-5754595_why-bali-best-driver-driver-icons-hd-png.png as badge',
```

as tableName.columnNmae as alias
because of dot using in extra column name:

to avoid this behavior 
you should use MySQL Backticks `` :

```
 `https://www.pngitem.com/pimgs/m/575-5754595_why-bali-best-driver-driver-icons-hd-png.png as badge`,
            `3.5 as rating`
```

more details in:
https://riptutorial.com/mysql/example/18445/backticks-usage